# Compile QuickFIX C++ with MySQL Support

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm trying to compile the quickfix c++ from the source code downloaded, I enabled the have mysql option in the config_windows.h file but it generates error.
I checked the documentation site but i'm having problems understanding this instruction

#define HAVE_MYSQL 1 Compiles MySQL support into QuickFIX. If you enable this option, the mysql include and library directories must be in the Visual Studio search paths.

And that seems to be my problem i guess, If someone could elaborate that statement further i'll be greatful.

Thanks

Comment: Solved! Figured I had to download the libraries for the databases and include in the source.

Comment: Maybe you could answer (and accept) your own question, just to help other people who could have the same problem. Otherwise, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Figured I had to download the libraries for the databases and include in the source.